# Populating and XML template with LINQ to XML?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have multiple XML templates and I would like to populate them using LINQ to XML, but I wasn't sure how to get started, meaning how to correctly read in the XML file (Best method) and populate attributes and Nodes (InnerText).  Also, how do create new elements and attributes in the existing template as well remove/update existing ones?  Here is an example of a template:

```
<Person age="age">
<FirstName></FirstName>
<LastName></LastName>
<Children>
<Name></Name>
</Children>
</Person>
```

In the abvoe, the age attribute is a placeholder, FirstName, LastName and Name under Children are placeholders.  Let's also assume that I either want to remove Names under children or add names as well.  Also lets assume I want to add a DOB element inside Person with day, month, year attributes?

Comment: DOB should be just a DateTime that you read and then get the day, month and year from.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example.  You build a class for each template.  I'm using this library extension class (XElementExtensions.cs) from: https://github.com/ChuckSavage/XmlLib/

```
public class Person
{
    XElement self;
    public Person(XElement person) { self = person; }

    // Age should be a value of Now minus DOB in years.
    public int Age { get { return DateTime.Now.Year - DOB.Year; } }

    public DateTime DOB
    {
        get { return self.Get("DOB", DateTime.MinValue ); } // choose a default date that works for you
        set { self.Set("DOB", value, true); } // true set as attribute
    }

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return self.Get("FirstName", string.Empty); }
        set { self.Set("FirstName", value, false); } // false set as child node
    } 

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return self.Get("LastName", string.Empty); }
        set { self.Set("LastName", value, false); }
    } 

    public Children Children
    {
        get { return new Children(self.GetElement("Children")); }
    }
}

public class Children
{
    XElement self;
    public Children(XElement children) { self = children; }

    public Child this[string name]
    {
        get 
        { 
            return self.Elements("Name")
                         .Select(x => new Child(x))
                         .FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == name);
        }
    }

    public Child this[int index]
    {
         get { return new Child(self.Elements("Name").ElementAt(index)); }
    }

    public void Add(string name)
    {
         Child child = this[name];
         if(null == child)
         {
             child = new Child(new XElement("Name"));
             child.Name = name;
             self.Add(child.self);
         }
         else
             throw new ArgumentException("Child with name: "+ name +" already exists!");
    }
}

public class Child
{
    internal XElement self;
    public Child(XElement child) { self = child; }

    // You can have an Age/DOB for the child as well, or remove these two properties.
    // Age should be a value of Now minus DOB in years.
    public int Age { get { return DateTime.Now.Year - DOB.Year; } }

    // DOB is an attribute as self.Value in Name erases all child nodes when set.
    public DateTime DOB
    {
        get { return self.Get("DOB", DateTime.MinValue ); } // choose a default date that works for you
        set { self.Set("DOB", value, true); }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return self.Value }
        set { self.Value = value; }
    } 
}
```

If you want to specify null as the default for any Get() then you need to specify the type to Get with `Get<Type>("node", null)`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to take a look at the [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) and its XDocument class. It makes navigation and editing of an xml document very easy.

Answer (score -1):

Look at this [site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb688087.aspx) for samples of linq to xml